# Android : How to forbird re-creation of Activity when orientation changed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

I have an Android Activity with Frgment. When my application is started, a listview is loaded with 10 elements which are sent from a server. (simple request).

When i change the orientation of my device, the activity is recreated, i see also the spinner with my request to load my listview.

How can i do to forbid re-creation of Activity ?

I already set the flag :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

And onConfigurationChanged :

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: As per my knowledge if you use `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" `  The view will not be redrawn. ARe sure that you are using for correct activity

Comment: Yes when i add this flag, the view is not recreated when i change the orientation. But the display is not correct. It take only a part of the screen.

Comment: That is because you possibly need to create separate portrait and landscape layouts, and when rotating the phone, inflate the correct one.

Comment: @wawanopoulos you need take the suggestion of Mikel in this case I feel , can you attach the screen-shot of both modes.

Comment: @RahulPatil In fact, when the orientation change, the activity is not recreated. When i go in landscape mode, i well see my activity but it doesn't take all the width screen. In landscape mode, i think that the width of what i see is the same that the width which is displayed in portrait mode.

Comment: Ya , Try using the `weight` concept for layouts

Answer (score 0):

You then want to override

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
}
```

in your activity, with what you want to do on orientation/keyboardHidden/screenSize.

Setting the flag in the manifest tells the app that you want to handle those configuration changes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and keep state of all the values that you need when orientation changes.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putString("jsonArrayString", jsonArrayStrin);
  // etc.
}
```

This value will be passed to the onCreate and/or onRestoreInstanceState. You can retrieve this using following :

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  String myArrayString = savedInstanceState.getString("jsonArrayString");
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the orientation to change, you can also prevent it in the manifest. Just specify in the activity element the attribute: android:screenOrientation